# modal bootstrap and html tag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to look a little bit on bootstrap. I would like that when I click "Create New" I get the modal box up. I can easily make it with a bootstrap button, but I cannot get a normal a tag to invoke it. It is probably something really basic I do wrong?

```
<a href><h6>Create New</h6>
 <div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
</a>
```

JS:

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
            message: 'Hi Apple!',
            buttons: [{
                label: 'Button 1'
            }, {
                label: 'Button 2',
                cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                action: function(){
                    alert('Hi Orange!');
                }
            }, {
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle',
                label: 'Button 3',
                cssClass: 'btn-warning'
            }, {
                label: 'Close',
                action: function(dialogItself){
                    dialogItself.close();
                }
            }]
        });
</script>
```

Comment: First, add the opening script tag to your JS. Then, it is more easy to see what is going on with your code if you create a Fiddle. (This is yours: https://jsfiddle.net/mebz03pb/)

Comment: Also, viewing your code... The HTML is upside-down. You should a little more into this before asking. Here are good examples: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp  http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-modals/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try looking at [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)?

This...

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Create New</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It of course make sense to set an id :-/ What does the <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> means?

Comment: It is just a cross on the right top corner of modal, which dismiss the modal.

Comment: &times; is an html code for `×`. `aria-hidden="true"` means [Indicates that the element and all of its descendants are not visible or perceivable to any user as implemented by the author.](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/)

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you try to use `BootstrapDialog` to run your modal. I don't think it is a better solution, because in fact you need to write the as much code in Javascript, as in built-in modal in Bootstrap in HTML.

For your case, you need this:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><h6>Create New</h6></a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Hi, apple!
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button 1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="alert('Hi Orange!')">Button 2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Button 3</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```